# How to loop and simplify code of multiple side scrolling buttons that scrolls specific row in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, button, scroll, overflow

I am new in javascript and I have been experiencing problems in trying to solve on how can I create multiple side scrolling buttons that scrolls specific row in javascript. This is my code in javascript

```
const next = document.querySelector('#next');
const back = document.querySelector('#back');
const next1 = document.querySelector('#next1');
const back1 = document.querySelector('#back1');

next.onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector('#con').scrollLeft += 1308;
};
back.onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector('#con').scrollLeft -= 1308;
};
next1.onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector('#con1').scrollLeft += 1308;
};
back1.onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector('#con1').scrollLeft -= 1308;
};
```

I have tried to create my own loop but I think I need to be knowledgeable to even create one. I am expecting  answers from experienced devs on how to simplify the code with loops and event listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to create the html elements with some info in them in order to achieve what you are looking for.
We will need:

- classes - one class for back button, one class for next buttom
- attributes - we will use the attributes in order to tell which row we want to move (by row id).+ attribute with the value to scroll to.

for example:

```html
  <div data-row="con" data-scroll="1308" class="nxt_btn">Next</div>
  <div data-row="con" data-scroll="1308" class="bck_btn">Back</div>

  <div data-row="con1" data-scroll="1308" class="nxt_btn">Next</div>
  <div data-row="con1" data-scroll="1308" class="bck_btn">Back</div>
```

now on js we can get all next buttons and all back buttons by class. and then to add click event.

```js
const nxt_btns = document.querySelectorAll(".nxt_btn");
const bck_btns = document.querySelectorAll(".bck_btn");

for (let n_btn of nxt_btns) {
  n_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // getting the row id from attribute
    const row = n_btn.getAttribute("data-row");
     // getting to where to scroll from attribute 
    const to = n_btn.getAttribute("data-scroll");
    
    // adding the action. notice im adding the row with literals `${row}` and im parsing the to value, because it comes as a string and we need it as int (number). 
 document.querySelector(`#${row}`).scrollLeft += parseInt(to, 10);
  });
}

for (let b_btn of bck_btns) {
  b_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const row = b_btn.getAttribute("data-row");
    const to = b_btn.getAttribute("data-scroll");
    document.querySelector(`#${row}`).scrollLeft -= parseInt(to, 10);
  });
}
```

Here is a codesandbox example.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pensive-mendeleev-9j5kzv

One more thing you can do to make it in one loop is to add another attribute `data-dir` and set it `next` or `back` and based on it to decide about the click event behaviour. (if you want i can add an example how to achieve it)

Notice i put all the code inside the html file, only to make it easier to see everything and understand. ofcourse a good practice is to seperate the js from the html.

Next thing you can do, is to create a loop to generate the html for you (rows and buttons - but this requires more data, and probably you will need to ask it as another question)

Comment: Thanks alot!, looping the html is nice but might be another job  and would require to recode everything

Comment: @Frost another suggstion will be to simply create an array of objects, loop through the array and at the same loop to generate the html and adding the click event. so if you have more sections to create you can simply add another object to the array. (you can also store objects in database or localstorage and create more sections on the fly)

Comment: Yes I think that would make the code more simple, thanks for the code and suggestions!

Comment: @Frost if you want i can edit my answer and put a code snippet of how you can achieve it..